# reinstall owncloud freenas without losing data

Tags: data-recovery, truenas, owncloud, reinstall

We recently had a major poweroutage that caused our freenas server to bootdown (Battery Backups ran out of juice).  When rebooting the server owncloud failed to restart and was throwing a php error.  It appears it was related to a permission problem.  We had not upgraded owncloud in a while on the freenas server so we figured we just run the update and it would fix the permission problems (I know lazy).  Well, the upgrade went through on the freenas side without a problem, but when accessing the owncloud interface it is now asking to upgrade to 9.1.  When we push this button, it says :

```
Exception: Updates between multiple major versions and downgrades are unsupported.
```

Is there a way to reinstall owncloud without losing all the current data in the freenas jail?  We can't start from scratch as their is over 300GB worth of user data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a workaround to the issue.  I changed the version number in the config file under /usr/pbi/owncloud-amd64/www/owncloud/config from the old version to the new version and the update went through successfully without a hitch.  Everything is back to working as it should. I installed a separate instance of owncloud with the latest version and compared the two config files and that was the only thing that was different.

Answer (score 0):

Which version have yu used before? I would recommend to switch to Nextcloud because they will support to skip major version upgrades and the project is overall more active. So the recommended way to fix this is:

Switch back to the original ownCloud version and then jump step by step to newer version until you reached ownCloud 9.0 From then you can jump to Nextcloud 10.
Upgrading is documented here: https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/10/admin_manual/maintenance/upgrade.html

Comment: It was 8.1, but how do I downgrade back to 8.1 on freenas for owncloud without loosing user data though?